# Postman tests are failing when running through NewMan tool

Tags: json, postman, postman-newman

I have ran a collection(with 3 scripts) and my variables declared at collection level and i'm using 1 data csv file to get the input and the collections to be run in 2 iterations.
The above scripts are passing when i ran through postman tool
but failing when i ran through Newman. Donot have any idea about why these are failing.
**Asertions seems to be failing **
Errors are like :
1.
Descriptionexpected 116 to equal '116'
Locationassertion:1 in test-script
RequestGet Journal AllocationIteration1
2.
DescriptionCannot read property '0' of undefined
Locationassertion:3 in test-script
RequestCreate Client Payee TransactionIteration1